# Sampling: when is multivariate random variable interpretation dissimilar to repeated realization of single random variable interpretation

Tags: sampling, random-variable, independence

After reading many different posts on this site regarding the relationship between random variables and samples, I still have one lingering question (my apologies if I've missed any post explicitly addressing this).

It is my understanding that a sample (comprised of $n$ observations) has two interpretations:

1. The sample $s=\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$ is comprised of $n$ realizations of the random variable $X$.
2. The sample $s=\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$ is comprised of one realization of random variable $X_1$, one realization of a *different* random variable $X_2$, $\cdots$, and one realization of a *different* random variable $X_n$.

My question is the following:

> When does the equivalence of these two interpretations break down?

Does it ever break down? Or is this equivalence only false in the event that at least one $X_i$ is **not** independent and identically distributed from/to the others?